# html two table horizontally align center

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I center two tables side by side?

I am centering the single table, But I could not center two tables,There is a simple way but i could not,  How can i do with css?

My codes are as follows:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
 body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">Val1</td>
      <td class="text-center">a</td>
      <td class="text-left">%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">AÇILAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">KALAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by centering?

Comment: Do you want something like this `-------- Table - another Table -------`

Answer (score 0):

By adding 'display:inline-table;' css to your .table-fill css class, may solve your problem

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
 body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
  display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">Val1</td>
      <td class="text-center">a</td>
      <td class="text-left">%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">AÇILAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">KALAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

added `text-align:center;` to body or a parent of the tables and `display:inline-table;` to the `.table-fill` check it on full page view.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
 body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-align:center;
}
/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right">Val1</td>
      <td class="text-center">a</td>
      <td class="text-left">%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table-fill" style="" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">1</th>
      <th class="text-left">2</th>
      <th class="text-left">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">AÇILAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">KALAN SANDIK</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
      <td class="text-left">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```